# Python if statment's results into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` from a simple if statement result with no success. Could you show me the right method, please? This is what I have so far but the value of `discrep` is not added to the `DataFrame`.

```
discrepancy_value=round(system_availability.iloc[0,0]-data_av.iloc[0,0],2)
discrep=[]
if discrepancy_value>1:
    discrep=discrepancy_value
else:
    discrep=r'Discrepancy is not significant'
discrepancy=pd.DataFrame()
discrepancy['Discrepancy']=discrep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is, that you are trying to insert a single value in the dataframe. The dataframe needs lists, not values.
What you should be doing is:

```
discrep=[]
if discrepancy_value>1:
    discrep.append(discrepancy_value)
else:
    discrep.append(r'Discrepancy is not significant')
discrepancy=pd.DataFrame()
discrepancy['Discrepancy']=discrep
```

Answer (score 0):

On one line:

```
discrepancy = pd.DataFrame({'Discrepancy': [discrepancy_value if discrepancy_value > 1 else r'Discrepancy is not significant']})
```

Comment: thanks. i've just started python the one line version is on the next level. maybe in two weeks time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a column on an empty dataset with 0 rows. If there would be already rows in the dataframe the following would add the same value to all rows:

```
discrepancy['Discrepancy']=discrep
```

But because there are no rows in the dataframe, the column is not added to any row.

You could append a new row with the column value like this:

```
discrepancy.append([{'Discrepancy': discrep}])
```

Or add the row already when you create the dataframe

```
discrepancy=pd.DataFrame([{'Discrepancy': discrep}])
```